# Colourize buffer names differently for the files located in different directories

Tags: buffers, regular-expressions, faces

I am working upon 2 projects that have similar structure. And sometimes occasionally modify a file in the wrong buffer.

So I desided to set different colours for the files in the different projects:

```
(add-hook 'window-buffer-change-functions
  `(lambda (window)
     (interactive)
     (let ((full-name (buffer-file-name)))
       (cond
         ((string-match ".*/project_1/" full-name)
           (set-face-attribute 'mode-line-buffer-id (selected-frame) :foreground "orange"))
         ((string-match ".*/project_2/" full-name)
           (set-face-attribute 'mode-line-buffer-id (selected-frame) :foreground "violet"))
         (t
           (set-face-attribute 'mode-line-buffer-id (selected-frame) :foreground "white"))))))
```

Questions:

1. When the files from different projects are opened side by side, the colour of the last one is used.
2. When the colour changed for the first time a strange circle appers.
3. Is is possible to use `window` parameter, instead of calling `buffer-file-name` and `selected-frame`?

[image]

Comment: Pose only one question per post, please.

Comment: Have you noticed that the code above gives  #<frame *Messages* - GNU Emacs at OoO 0x55a3ffb484a8>) signaled (wrong-type-argument stringp nil) on all `*xxxx*` buffers (check out the *Messages* buffer)? What can be the reason for this? How to eliminate this? By the way: the code works OK also without `(interactive)`.

Comment: Use: `(let ((full-name (if (buffer-file-name) (buffer-file-name) "" )))` to avoid the problem with `wrong-type-argument stringp nil`.

Comment: @Claudio Sometimes the buffer has no files attached, and your improvement will fix this.

Comment: @Claudio Unfortunately, I am unable to do the colourizing with individual windows when the frame is split.

Comment: See my answer for the full code of the fix colorizing non-fille buffers as gray and keeping colorizing non-project files as white.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work for me (?).  I made this change, but it likely doesn't matter:

There's no need to use the prefix `.*`, and no reason to set the `match-data`, so you can just use, e.g., `(string-match-p "/project_1/" full-name)`.

Do you see the same problem if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q`? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

---

Also, you might just want to set variable `mode-line-buffer-identification` instead of modifying face `mode-line-buffer-id`. E.g.:

```lisp
(let ((strg  (car mode-line-buffer-identification)))
  (when (and (consp strg)  (eq (car strg) ':eval))
    (setq strg  (car (eval (cadr strg)))))
  (setq mode-line-buffer-identification
        (list (propertize strg 'face (if (string-match-p "/project1/" strg)
                                         'highlight
                                       'font-lock-warning-face)))))
```

---

Your comment here said:

> The code works, but it highlights the names for 2 different projects with the same colour based upon who was opened the latest. Is it possible to make 1 orange and 1 violet? `mode-line-buffer-id` modifies the colour for entire frame with all the windows.

`C-h v window-buffer-change-functions` includes this, which explains that, I think -- I think this is happening with your code:

> Functions specified by the default value are *called for each frame* if
> at least one window on that frame has been added, deleted or changed
> its buffer since the last redisplay.  In this case **the frame is passed
> as argument**.

That help output also says this:

> Functions specified buffer-locally are *called for each window* showing
> the corresponding buffer if and only if that window has been added or
> changed its buffer since the last redisplay.  In this case **the window
> is passed as argument**.

So maybe try using `add-hook` with non-`nil` 4th argument, `LOCAL`.  In this case, the window, not the frame, is passed to the hook function as the argument.

Comment: The code works, but it highlights the names for 2 different projects with the same colour based upon who was opened the latest. Is it possible to make 1 orange and 1 violet? `mode-line-buffer-id` modifies the colour for entire frame with all the windows.

Comment: Tried LOCAL. Gives an error if added to (add-hook ... LOCAL) . What do you mean with 4th argument and LOCAL?

Comment: `C-h f add-hook`.

Comment: @Claudio No, LOCAL is a formal parameter. Put `t` there as an actual parameter.

Comment: @user4035 : to put `t` for LOCAL it is probably necessary to put for example 0 for DEPTH like this : `(add-hook 'window-buffer-change-functions (lambda ... ) 0 t` right? The result is that the coloring does not work at all, right or wrong?

Comment: @Claudio Yes, I tried `(add-hook 'window-buffer-change-functions (lambda ... ) 0 t`, it didn't work. But the syntax is correct. Also in my version of Emacs I don't have this help message about buffer-local functions. Maybe, it is done only for the neweset Emacs? Mine is 28.1.

Comment: @Drew What is your version of Emacs? I don't have the text about buffer local in my `set-face-attribute` manual that you quoted. Mine is 28.1.

Comment: @user4035: I didn't say anything about `set-face-attribute`. `LOCAL` is an optional arg to `add-hook`, and has been probably since Day One (at least as far back as Emacs 20). When you provide a non-`nil` value for `LOCAL` you can leave `DEPTH` as `nil` - that has the same effect as  `0` depth.

Comment: @Drew No, no, I am talking about this text: "That help output also says this: Functions specified buffer-locally are called for each window showing the corresponding..." - is this from help to `set-face-attribute`? I don't have this in my Emacs.

Comment: Those quotes are under my sentence that talks about variable `window-buffer-change-functions`. It's the doc (help string and Elisp manual) that has the quoted text. That text explains, I think, the behavior you were getting and didn't understand. And the text is present in older Emacs versions, where the var is misnamed `window-buffer-change-hook`.

Answer (score 0):

The Emacs elisp `set-face-attribute` accepts only frames as parameter, not windows. This makes it impossible to use it for setting of different colors in different windows of the same frame.

A work-around it which could be accepted as an intermediate solution (until a way of window-specific change of the font face color is pointed out in another answer) will be to launch Emacs twice and position its frames side by side instead of side by side windows in only once launched Emacs.

Below ready to use in an initialization file code which fixes the problem with throwing warning signals to the `*Message*` buffer while viewing non-file buffers. The code allows also to set the color in which non-file buffer names are displayed in the modeline.

In order to improve the orientation even more it adds code for displaying the full path of the file (or the buffer name) in the title bar.

```
;; ----------------------------------------------------------------------
(defun current-buffer-filename-or-the-buffer-name ()
  (let ((buf (if (active-minibuffer-window)
                 (window-buffer (minibuffer-selected-window))
               (current-buffer))))
    ;; use full file name if there one, otherwise just buffer name.
    (or (buffer-file-name buf) (buffer-name buf))))
;; Show the buffer names displayed in the modeline in different colors
;; and display full paths of the files in the title bar
(add-hook 'window-buffer-change-functions
  " Show buffer names in the modeline in different colors "
  `(lambda (&optional window &rest rest)
     (setq frame-title-format '(:eval (concat "Emacs :      " (current-buffer-filename-or-the-buffer-name))))
     (let ((full-file-name (if (buffer-file-name) (buffer-file-name) "")))
       (cond
         ((string-match ".*/project_1/" full-name)
           (set-face-attribute 'mode-line-buffer-id (selected-frame) :foreground "orange"))
         ((string-match ".*/project_2/" full-name)
           (set-face-attribute 'mode-line-buffer-id (selected-frame) :foreground "violet"))
         ((buffer-file-name)  ;; any other files:  white
           (set-face-attribute 'mode-line-buffer-id (selected-frame) :foreground "white"))))))
         (t                   ;; non-file buffers: gray
           (set-face-attribute 'mode-line-buffer-id (selected-frame) :foreground "gray"))))))
```